# How do I use the File Exporter with OpenTelemetry

Tags: c#, .net, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have a .NET C# app with basic OpenTelemetry (1.7.0) implemented. I'm looking to export the metrics to json or text file. My understanding is that this is possible using the File Exporter. Do you have an example of how to achieve this? I'm new to OpenTelemetry.

**TelemetryBuilder.cs**

```
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;

namespace OpenTelemetrySample.OpenTelemetryBuilder;

    public static class OpenTelemetryBuilder
    {
        public static void OpenTelemetryInstrumenter(IServiceCollection services, string ApplicationName)
        {
            services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                  .ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService(ApplicationName))
                  .WithTracing(tracing => tracing
                      .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                      .AddConsoleExporter()
                      .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
                            {
                                options.Endpoint = new Uri("https://newrelicendpoint");
                                options.Headers = "api-key=somekey";
                            })
                      )
                  .WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
                      .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                      .AddConsoleExporter()
                      .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
                        {
                            options.Endpoint = new Uri("https://newrelicendpoint");
                            options.Headers = "api-key=somekey";
                        })
                      );
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
using OpenTelemetrySample.Models;
using OpenTelemetrySample.OpenTelemetryBuilder;

namespace OpenTelemetrySampleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add Framework MVC services to the Container.
            builder.Services.AddMvc();

            //Application Service
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();

            OpenTelemetryBuilder.OpenTelemetryInstrumenter(builder.Services, "student-list-app");

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File exporter is not implemented in .NET. You can send data to OpenTelemetry Collecter and then use https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/fileexporter.

Collector should be able to forward data to most providers, including newrelic.

Similar issue on the [OTel .NET repository](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/5231)